# Different app behavior on simulator and device

Tags: actions-on-google

My actions on google app give correct responses on the simulator but when asked the exact same question on a device it gives completely different answer not related to that intent. What is the reason behind this?

For example: 
I want to know about Washington DC? when I write this in Simulator it works as it should. However, while testing it on the phone it gives completely different responses which are based on the trains, which I defined in other intents.

Also, entities of both the intents are completely different and I have used correct parameters and designed different training phrases for both as well.

Comment: Without concrete examples, it is *very* difficult to help you figure out the problem. Please update your question with as many details as you can. See [How do I ask a Good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Okay, I have edited and added the details.

Comment: Unfortunately, that really doesn't help us. Showing us your code, screen shots of the intents, screen shots of it running on the simulator and on the phone - these will help. [Hey Google, I Need Help With My Action](https://medium.com/google-developer-experts/hey-google-i-need-help-with-my-action-8cf09714a20d)

Comment: The more information you give us, the better chance we'll be able to help you figure out what is going on. We can't read your mind.